# Disallowed user agent from google oauth

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth

When I open google oauth flow in web view in iOS app I get an error about disallowed user agent. How can I get pass this error?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0):

you need to open the authorization window in the default browser on the device

it sounds like you are trying to use a web view